# Conditionnal display with twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8, drupal-views

I'm using Twig in Views to rewrite output with condition.

```
{{ field_illus_lycee }}
{% if field_titre_pour_views is defined %}
    {% if field_titre_pour_views is not empty %} 
        {{ field_titre_pour_views }}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {{ title }}
{% endif %}  
<span class="accroche-admin">{{ body }}</span>
```

I want to display `field_titre_pour_views` only if it exists and isn't empty, otherwise the regular title should be displayed. But at this point the regular title isn't displayed.Inspired by [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/611/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-and-it-s-not-empty-with-twig-using-a-short-syntax)

I don't understand which mistake I've made.

EDIT: correct code

```
 {{ field_illus_lycee }}
        {% if field_titre_pour_views is defined %}
            {% if field_titre_pour_views is not empty %} 
                {{ field_titre_pour_views }}
{% else %}
            {{ title }}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {{ title }}
        {% endif %}  
        <span class="accroche-admin">{{ body }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, to ask is to find...this code do the trick:

```
 {% if field_titre_pour_views |default %}
     {{ field_titre_pour_views }}
 {% else %}
     {{ title }}
 {% endif %}
```

Auto fixed :)
Hope it would help someone else.

Comment: Also note that was because there was no `else` statement for your second condition  `{% if field_titre_pour_views is not empty %}`. You were in the situation where the field was actually defined but empty.